# Where do global npm packages get installed on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-14.04

Where is the default global node_modules folder on Ubuntu. For example where would this get installed: `npm install -g gulp`

Comment: my gut tells me this would be better to ask on SU or AU (super user or ask ubuntu).

Comment: Not sure why you created this, there's plenty of information out there already.

Comment: I've had to google this several times and it always takes me a while to track down so I'm just posting it here to make it easier to find

Comment: well, like my original comment stated: this is more about a tool and less about an actual programming problem, so it should be on one of the aforementioned sites.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Run `npm root -g` to see the location, which varies. A common path is **/usr/local/lib/node_modules**.

For more info see the npm docs on [Global vs. Local installation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#global-installation)

Comment: You can also see that by running `npm root -g`

Comment: @Zirak please consider putting this as an answer as it's actually more useful than the accepted one, thanks!

Comment: The answer is actually incorrect. It's /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Comment: @Zirak His comment should be the answer--that link is long dead.

Comment: `npm root -g` yields `/usr/lib/node_modules` on my Ubuntu installation.

Comment: or at `/home/YOURNAMEINLOWERCASE/node_modules/`

Comment: `npm root -g` returns `/home/ubuntu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules` on EC2 ubuntu.

Comment: This answer is generally incorrect. As pointed out many times, npm root -g, will give you the actual location.

Comment: @Zirak should be the right answer.

Comment: @Zirak is the right answer. Upvoted.